# Xcode 7.3 syntax highlighting/autocomplete intermittently stops working

Tags: xcode, xcode7, syntax-highlighting, xcode7.3

Syntax highlighting in Xcode has been going on and off frequently for me. I'll just be typing (or sometimes not) and the syntax highlighting, autocomplete, and error checking features just stop working for several seconds and then come back.

[Video of the issue.](https://infinit.io/_/KmjLYFwkk)

I am almost exclusively writing Swift code with development snapshots.

```
Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175)  
Toolchain: Swift Development Snapshot 2016-05-09 (a)
OS X 10.11.5
Macbook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB
```

Installed plugins:

- Backlight
- GitDiff
- LigatureXcodePlugin
- Xvim

But I've also experienced this without any plugins loaded. I've experienced this at least back to the 7.X betas. But seems to be even worse with 7.3. Haven't tried Xcode 8 beta as it doesn't support the Swift dev snapshots.

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

#### Update

I noticed that when this error happens some error messages are written to Console:

```
7/14/16 12:28:41.121 Xcode[15239]: #DVTSourceControl Error: -300 The remote repository could not be found.
Underlying Error: 
Method: __80-[DVTSourceControlManager remoteBranchFromRepository:forBranch:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_2
7/14/16 12:28:45.094 Xcode[15239]:  IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: Connection interrupted
7/14/16 12:28:45.230 Xcode[15239]:  IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:28:45.231 Xcode[15239]:  IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:28:45.231 Xcode[15239]:  IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:29:57.888 Xcode[15239]:  IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: Connection interrupted
7/14/16 12:29:58.107 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:29:58.324 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:29:58.355 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:29:59.132 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:29:59.251 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:29:59.388 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:29:59.468 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:29:59.588 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:30:01.051 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:30:01.269 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:30:01.771 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:30:01.920 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:30:02.113 Xcode[15239]: [MT] IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: restoring service
7/14/16 12:30:08.139 Xcode[15239]: [default] Failed to updated bookmark for item (null) [1F5EEA59-15A1-49CA-89D8-30FA73C64572] - URL:file:///Users/me/work/HTTPFile/HTTPFile/HTTPFile.xcodeproj with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist."
7/14/16 12:30:08.139 Xcode[15239]: -[SFLListItem synthesizeMissingPropertyValues] Failed to updated bookmark for item (null) [1F5EEA59-15A1-49CA-89D8-30FA73C64572] - URL:file:///Users/me/work/HTTPFile/HTTPFile/HTTPFile.xcodeproj with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist."
7/14/16 12:30:08.140 Xcode[15239]: [default] Failed to updated bookmark for item (null) [1F5EEA59-15A1-49CA-89D8-30FA73C64572] - URL:file:///Users/me/work/HTTPFile/HTTPFile/HTTPFile.xcodeproj with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist."
7/14/16 12:30:08.140 Xcode[15239]: -[SFLListItem synthesizeMissingPropertyValues] Failed to updated bookmark for item (null) [1F5EEA59-15A1-49CA-89D8-30FA73C64572] - URL:file:///Users/me/work/HTTPFile/HTTPFile/HTTPFile.xcodeproj with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist."
7/14/16 12:30:12.000 Xcode[15239]:  IDESourceKitService: SourceKit Service error: Connection interrupted
```

Comment: I haven't installed any plugins and am experiencing the same issue. This is just a bug in Xcode, restarting Xcode always gets the autocomplete and highlighting working again.

Comment: Luckily, mine usually starts working again so I don't need to restart. But it happens over and over again, usually once every minute or so.